# Regex for removing line X when immediately followed by line Y

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a regex for removing line X when *immediately* followed by line Y.
I've tried this in a `foreach` (files previously gathered)

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
    say "Processing $file in $dir";

    open( my $fh, "<", "$file" )
      or die "Can't open < $file: $!";

    my $data = {};

    my $start = "X:";
    my $end   = "Y:";

    my $contents = do { local $/; <$fh> };

    my $count = 1;

    my $transformed = $contents;

    while ( $contents =~ /$start(.*?)$end/sg ) {
        say $1 if $1;
        my $formatted = $1;
        $formatted =~ s/\s+//g                  if $formatted;
        $data->{$file}->{$formatted} = $count++ if $formatted;
        $transformed =~ /($start.*?$end)/sg;
        my $removed = quotemeta($1)        if $1;
        $transformed =~ s/$removed/$end/sg if $removed;
    }

    push @results, $data if ($data);

    path($file)->spew_utf8($transformed);

}
```

but cannot get it to ignore the 'ignore example' below.

Text to process (Y *immediately* after X):

```
{
X: John Smith,
Y: 1234 Main Street
}
```

becomes

```
{
Y: 1234 Main Street
}
```

Text to ignore (Y not *immediately* after X):

```
{
X: John Smith,
X2: 1234567890,
Y: 1234 Main Street
}
```

Comment: The `g` in `$transformed =~ /($start.*?$end)/sg;` makes no sense and can cause really weird behaviour. /// `my $removed = quotemeta($1) if $1;` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```perl
s/^X:.*\n(?=Y:)//m;
```

This is short for

```perl
s/^X:[^\n]*\n(?=Y:)//m;
```

`g` can be used to remove multiple occurrences.

You don't want `s` with the first as `s` changes the definition of `.`.